# SQL Keep default order but apply suborder for left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by, mariadb

I am loading large amount of data for creating a feed. In this process there must be a left join that adds additional data. So you understand there is a high demand on performance.

Ordering by the primary ID is not needed - therefore unnecessary, but what is needed is ordering the left-joined part.

Consider this example:

```
SELECT p.*, atts.name 
FROM products as p 
LEFT JOIN attributes as atts ON p.product_id = atts.product_id
```

Now what I need is to add something like

```
ORDER BY ??DEFAULT_PRODUCT_ORDER??, atts.position ASC
```

I tried to search for this issue but the closest thing I found was ending with group by / max answers...

Using: MySQL/MariaDB

**EDIT:** I also thought about preprocessing the attributes in SQL by subquery that would order them and concatenate them as 1 column - but that would not be much efficient would it?

Comment: where is the default order stored?, can you add your table structures

Comment: @happymacarts nowhere :) the goal is to load products table "as is" (therefore in the most efficient way)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your desire. you want it as-is and sorted provide some sample data and what you want it to look like. How many rows of data are you talking about?

Comment: @happymacarts checkout the edit, you might understand it more, By default, when you don't add `ORDER` to the statement the results have no order determinated, so they are loaded in the most efficient/the fastest way . So the table structure is completely irrelevant here (no more than I've included).

Comment: well if your tables are indexed the performance hit of adding an order by is not that heavy unless you are talking about multiple 100k+ results. you could add a [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: what results are you getting with what you have tried? vs what do you want to see?

Comment: @happymacarts results I am getting I just found are grouped anyway, so the group_concat() might be the way in the end, however this question is more of a generic question - how to keep the primary default order but order the items "within themselves" , I've seen some practices with ORDER BY NULL ?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what exactly you are looking for there are a few things you could try

```
SELECT p.*, group_concat(atts.name) 
FROM products as p 
LEFT JOIN attributes as atts ON p.product_id = atts.product_id

Group BY /*all columns not included in aggregate (noc necc for mysql but other dbs like mssql get crazy about that*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The "default order" for the output of a `SELECT` is "whatever".

Are the tables InnoDB?  I will assume so.

What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `products`?  I will assume `(product_id)`

(It would be handy if you had provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.)

Does `attributes` have `PRIMARY KEY(product_id, position)`?  If not, it should.  This is part of the performance issue.

Then you need `ORDER BY p.product_id, atts.position`, but none of the indexes will really be used since an index cannot span two tables.  (No it won't help to change `p.` to `atts`.  The optimizer is smart enough to see `p.product_id` and `atts.product_id` as interchangeable.)

But...  Do you really need `LEFT`??  With it there, you are displaying `NULL` for `atts.name` when there is no atts row.  Maybe that never happens?  In which case, reove `LEFT` so that the `JOIN` can go the other way.  *Now* the `ORDER BY` and `INDEXes` can come into play.

Without `LEFT`, I predict that `EXPLAIN SELECT...` will show `atts` as the first table, and do a full table scan of it.  Then it will reach into the other table repeatedly, using its PK.  No "Using temporary" or "Using filesort".

(If you want further discussion, edit the question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.)

Comment: let's assume `attributes` has no such `PRIMARY KEY` because same position can occure for any number of attributes for the same `product_id`. Can you elaborate on how does that affect performance? Same for InnoDB vs MyISAM ?
Anyway this is really a general question - so what you can't assume from the query consider non-existing. LEFT is definitely needed, because all products are needed, altough only some may have attributes - am I wrong?

Comment: `LEFT` --  OK.  Use InnoDB.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.